# NFC tag v1.0 & arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, nfc

My teacher just gave me a NFC tag v1.0 for a project. I have to use my phone to unlock a door.

I searched on internet and I just found this code:

```
#include "NfcTag.h"
#include <Wire.h>

NfcTag nfcTag;
int led = 5;
bool flag = false;
bool preFlag = false;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
  nfcTag.init();
}

void loop(){
  flag = nfcTag.readByte(EEPROM_I2C_LENGTH-1) == 0xff?true:false;
  if(flag != preFlag){
    Serial.println("get remote NFC control signal!");
    if(flag == true){
      Serial.println("led will light up!");
      digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    }else{
      Serial.println("led will turn dark!");
      digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    }
    preFlag = flag;
  }
  delay(5*1000);
}
```

This come from their wiki: http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-NFC_Tag/

I can connect with the phone and use it to change blocks. The problem is that when I try it, the LED just doesn't work at all. I tried the LED and he is working, I also tried the Digital pin on the Arduino UNO with the LED and it works as well. Also, the monitor doesn't show any off those printLn.

I used this way to connect them:

SCL - RX

SDA - TX

GND - GND

5V - VCC

I also used a code to debug, but no matter what address I use to readByte, I will always get the number 127 even after using the phone to change it with the app.

```
#include "NfcTag.h"
#include <Wire.h>

NfcTag nfcTag;
bool flag = false;
bool preFlag = false;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("starting sequence");
  nfcTag.init();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println("checking for nfc");
  //flag = nfcTag.readByte(EEPROM_I2C_LENGTH-1) == 0xff?true:false;
  //Serial1.println(flag);
  Serial.println(nfcTag.getICNumber());
  Serial.println(nfcTag.getAFI());
  Serial.println(nfcTag.getRFU());
  Serial.println(nfcTag.getMemoryVolume());
  Serial.println("result:");
  Serial.println(nfcTag.readByte(EEPROM_I2C_LENGTH-1)); //I tried changeing manualy the value, but the output still 127.

  delay(2000);

}
```

Output:

```
checking for nfc
127
127
32639
8355711
result:
127
```

If I could put the LED working, I have already a transistor with a power converter on the exit of the pin5, so the door can be unlocked.

By the way, I don't know why sometimes the NFC doesn't work and after some tries it start working again.

Any help will be appreciate :) Thanks.

Comment: Why did you connect I2C to UART?

Comment: You are using the wrong pins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct connection for the I2C pins is:

- SCL - PC5 (Analog A5)
- SDA - PC4 (Analog A4)

[This](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-NFC/) part supports Uart communications as you wired it. The [link](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-NFC_Tag/) you provided for the part you are using only support I2C and will not work as you wired it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer/explanation, it's working now!